# Java How to Render and Update Pixel Array to JPanel/JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I'm looking to implement a program that has a 2D array of objects each of which contains a color. Every T milliseconds, I want to perform some update operation (for simplicity's sake, say assigning a new random color to each object). Then render this new array of colors to the screen.

The main way I saw for rendering a pixel array was to use a BufferedImage, putting it in an ImageIcon, putting that in a JLabel and putting that on a JPanel. I implemented this and am able to render stuff to the screen but the paradigm doesn't really allow for periodic content updates and re-renders.

What would be a better way to get this sort of periodic update and re-render functionality?

Comment: Draw your object in `paintComponent` method of main class.

Comment: Use `java.swing.Timer` for periodic updates.

Comment: *"but the paradigm doesn't really allow for periodic content updates and re-renders."* Sure it does! The `BufferedImage` can be used as the 'pixel array'. It provides methods like `setRGB(..)` to change it. Once changed, `repaint()` the label to see the changes in the GUI.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: thoughts on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45660602/522444) and my comments?